# How to implement Authorize.net in android?

Tags: android, authorize.net

I would like to create a credit card app to take payments in Android using Authorize.net payment gateway.

I found some [example code here](https://developer.authorize.net/integration/fifteenminutes/android) from Authorize.net).

I followed the instructions however on step 2 I am not able to add its sdk as library with another project. When I create a new project as "ExampleActivity.java" & used this code as explained, I got red line errors on the AuthNet object & Environment.SANDBOX

Can anyone help me How to implement this code without errors?

Comment: Looking for a reference for this, but isn't there a rule from Google about in app payments are only allowed via Google Pay?

Comment: @Graham yeah.but i dont want to do payment through google.Thats y i used Authorize.net gateway

Answer (score 0):

- Add the Authrized_net_lib project  as a library project
- Add jar file authorize_net_lib jar file in your project
- Then Clean the project
- Now copy and paste given sample code

It will not give error.